# Get concatenation of parent and child names variations in one column

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

I have the following hierarchical query.

```
DECLARE @Id int = 1019;
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT a.Id, a.Cat_Fkey, a.CatEName
  FROM tblCategories a
  WHERE Id = @Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.Id, a.Cat_Fkey, a.CatEName
  FROM tblCategories a JOIN cte c ON a.Cat_Fkey = c.id
)
SELECT Cat_Fkey, Id, CatEName
FROM cte
```

This query gives the following outcome:

```
Cat_Fkey ID     Name
NULL     1019   Electronics
1019     1089   Mobile
1019     1092   Cameras
1089     1093   Mobile Child
```

So mobile and cameras are children of electronics, and mobile child is a child of mobile.

My question is how I can get the concatenation of parent and child names on in one column.

Sample output.

```
Concat_Column
Electronics Mobile
Electronics Cameras
Electronics Mobile Mobile Child
```

How can this be done dynamically, so whenever I add a new category, the query would get all possible variations.

Comment: i'm using sql server 2019

Comment: `SELECT T2.Name + ' ' + T1.Name FROM tbl T1 JOIN tbl T2 ON T1.Cat_Fkey = T2.ID WHERE t1.Cat_Fkey IS NOT NULL`